# Expression engine control panel theme not loading with forwarding slash

Tags: expresso-store

When I try to open control panel with forwarding slash, then it shows me broken login page theme, but when I try to open it without using slash then it loads properly. I guess somewhere it is not fetching css path , but i am not able to find it.

https://www.abc.com/control -- working
https://www.abc.com/control/ -- not working

Comment: Surely has something to do with your .htaccess. Inspect it yourself or ask the community by posting it here.

Comment: Yuri is correct, it's definitely something with your .htaccess . I would guess it's infinitely redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Updated correct redirection rules in htaccess and it works for me

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ------------------------------

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.+) $1 [R=301,L]

# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Include htaccess change to help others?

Comment: default expression engine htaccess works

Comment: Mayank, glad you solved it. I'm sure it will help other users if you edit your answer to include the code and a link to the docs.

Comment: Please find attach link for default expression engine .htaccess file https://gist.github.com/smaida/1225862